# Worst case lower bound for comparison sort

Tags: algorithms, sorting

It is known that in the worst case comparison sort takes $\Omega(nlgn)$ of time for n elements. Let's say I'm given $n$ elements as input to sort. Each input sequence of $n$ elements has $n/k$ subsequences with each subsequence having $k$ elements. Each subsequence is less than its subsequent sequence and greater than its preceding sequence. How do I find a lower bound $\Omega(nlgk)$ on the number of comparisons needed to solve this problem?

I tried to think about it if $n$=9,$k$=3 So I have 3 subsequences of 3 elements. I know that each subsequence has a worst case lower bound of $\Omega(klgk)$. I could just add these three up to get the overall lower bound, right?

If the answer to the above question is yes, then in the general case that there are $n/k$ subsequences I would have $\Omega((n/k)klgk)$?

Comment: Beware, $\omega$ `\omega` is not the same as $\Omega$ `\Omega`, comparison sort takes $\Omega(n \log n)$ time.

Comment: Thanks I actually couldn't find the mathjax notation for it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Anyway, this bound is a joke (that is, it is true, but the model is inappropriate). Sorting takes _linear_ time in terms of size of the input: each number takes approximately $\log n$ bits to store (under the assumption that the numbers are of size similar to size of $n$).

Comment: What is the concrete question you are asking? If you want to prove the lower bound, you could have just looked up the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort).